# Responsive picture tag in Vue with src set

Tags: vue.js

quick question.

I have in my HTML this picture tag to handle responsive images.

```
<picture>
 <source
   media=”(min-width: 900px)”
   srcset=“image-lg_1x.webp 1x, image-lg_2x.webp 2x”
   type=“image/webp” >
 <source
   media=”(min-width: 601px)”
   srcset=“image-md_1x.webp 1x, image-md_2x.webp 2x”
   type=“image/webp” >
 <source
   srcset=“image-sm_1x.webp 1x, image-sm_2x.webp 2x”
   type=“image/webp” >
 <img 
   srcset=“image-sm_1x.jpg 600w,
   image-md_1x.jpg 900w,
   image-lg_1x.jpg 1440w”
   src=“image_lg_1x.jpg”
   type=“image/jpeg”
   alt=”image description”>
</picture>
```

How can I use this syntax in Vue image tag?
I know that there is a component for responsive image but it need server side conversion. I already have my images!

Thank you

Comment: I guess you need to bind `srcset` with `:` directive. use as `:srcset` and please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I made component to automatize some functionality: [vue-picture-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-picture-element)